# StringRegExp pattern | Get the end of the path

Tags: regex, autoit

I have a path of picture like

```
$path = "C:\Users\nvquang\Desktop\New folder\AutoIT_ImageSearchUDF\GUI ImageSearch\Close.bmp"
```

I want to get only Close.bmp 
The function which i am trying to write looks like :

```
$fileName = StringRegExp($sFileOpenDialog,"GUI ImageSearch\(.*?).bmp",1)
```

But value of fileName is 0

 So now - what is wron with this function? I am not good at RegExp patterns but i am sure that is the best method to do what I want.

Comment: Why don't you just capture everything from the last backslash to the end with `[^\\]*$` ?

Comment: Are you aware that `StringRegExp` with `flag=1` returns an array? Your filename is in `$filen[0]` after `$file= StringRegExp($path,"[^\\]*$",1)`

Comment: Consider using [_PathSplit()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_PathSplit.htm)?

Answer (score -1):

> I am not good at RegExp patterns but i am sure that is the best method
> to do what I want.

As per [Documentation - Function Reference - StringTrimLeft](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringTrimLeft.htm) :

> Trims a number of characters from the left hand side of a string.

Example:

```
$sFilename = StringTrimLeft($sPath, StringInStr($sPath, '\', 0, -1))
```